# Escaping the "@" character on command line

Tags: bash, ftp

I am trying to get a simple command to upload a file for me in bash/ubuntu. I am using the `wput` command to do this. The account I am uploading to has the `@` symbol in it, and I think that is the reason I am having trouble getting it to log in correctly. When I try to log in, I get the following error message (IP address changed):

> Connecting to 1.1.1.1:21... connected!
>   Logging in as user@domain.com ... Error: Login-Sequence failed (Login authentication failed)
>   Skipping all files from this account...

The command that I am trying to run is:

```
wput -u file.txt ftp://user\@domain.com:password@ftp.domain.com/txt/
```

I have tried to use user@domain.com, and user\@domain.com. Has anyone tried something like this before?

When I use a GUI FTP client, and the same credentials, it works. That is how I tested to make sure that the user and pass actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to **urlencode**  it :

```
wput -u file.txt ftp://user%40domain.com:password@ftp.domain.com/txt/
```

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Sadly, I ended up with the same error. I will experiment to see if maybe I was wrong about the '@' being the issue, but I know I can log into a different account, from the same machine, that does not have the '@' in the user name. Thanks for the suggestion, I was really hoping it would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the @ symbol and/or the '%40' ascii code with a '+' in the username

NO => `ftp user@domain.com@ftp.domain.com`
NO => `ftp user%40domain.com@ftp.domain.com` 
YES => `ftp user+domain.com@ftp.domain.com`